# How to connect MicroStrategy 10 to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, driver, microstrategy

I have a problem on connecting microstrategy to a local database:

[image]

I'm unable to resolve this error, though I have tried everything in ODBC origins, and tried various drivers.

The server name is correct (`SQLExpress2017`)

If anyone knows how to resolve this issue, please help.

Answer (score 0):

**How to connect Micro Strategy 10 to SQL Server**

```
        We cannot connect the SQL SERVER 2017 through local by making the sql server dynamic access by allowing TCP/IP using(sql configuration manager)
```

**NOTE**
      1)Within your network your system be accessible  making dynamic sql server

After create odbc in Microstrategy server.in creating ODBC password should be your sql server username and password and create database instance in microstrategy.using datawarehouse catalog fetch the table based upon the instance you created